# how to export table data in to .csv file using shell script

Tags: shell-script

I need to get the data from mysql server and export to .csv file .i need to export data to new .csv file daily automatically.

query:select count(*) count,create_date from tabpush where status=1 and create_date between '2015-12-05' AND '2015-12-06' order by create_date desc ;

how do i do that ?

env:

linux:centos6.6

Comment: This query appears to produce only one row with one column.  You want to put that in a `.csv` file?

Comment: @RobertL Thanq for reply ,yes i need to put what that query returns into csv file

Comment: You can use `SELECT .. INTO outfile` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html ) to write a table to a text file with comma as a field delimeter and a newline as a record delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with MySQL's select ... into outfile.
Like this for example:

```
select count(*) count,create_date from tabpush 
where status=1 and create_date between subdate(current_date, 1) AND current_date()
order by create_date desc
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/daily.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```